# Pushing an existing svn repository to git

Tags: git, svn, git-svn, appharbor

I'm using SVN and I'm not planning to migrate to Git for now. I'd like to try out AppHarbor but currently you must use Git to deploy code to AppHarbor.

I'd like to continue using SVN but push to AppHarbor's git repository from time to time. Is there an easy way to achieve this?

Comment: YES! There is an easy way to manage your site. Take a look here:
[http://stofkn.blogspot.com/2012/02/getting-started-git-and-appharbor-easy.html](http://stofkn.blogspot.com/2012/02/getting-started-git-and-appharbor-easy.html) Just download msysgit( freaking CMD ) and TurtoiseGit (GUI :D ). Then you can manage your site with a few clicks as described in the article.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a git clone of your SVN repository with:

```
git svn clone --stdlayout <URL-OF-YOUR-SVN-REPOSITORY>
```

... and keep that up to date by periodically running:

```
git svn rebase
```

... in the directory created by the `git svn clone`.  You can then push from that git mirror of your Subversion repository to AppHarbor.