# How to get msysgit to clone a repository where I want it to go?

Tags: git, svn, cruisecontrol.net, git-svn, appharbor

New to git, not new to svn.

Attempting to clone an svn repository to push to appharbor as part of a build process, per something like [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8078467/pushing-an-existing-svn-repository-to-git).

However, msysgit always works from whatever directory the app starts in it seems.

I understand

```
git svn clone --stdlayout <my URL>
```

but is there an optional parameter to tell msysgit where to put this clone in my directory structure?

Similarly, is there a way to work the location into the "rebase" command?

Can't seem to find a reference for msysgit `git svn clone` syntax and hoping this is just a philosophical misunderstanding on my part about how git/msysgit works.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps I asked this too soon.

After some playing around, the syntax I found that works for me is:

```
git svn clone --stdlayout <Repo URL> "<Path where I'd like it to go>"
```

Whoops. Hope this saves someone else a few minutes at some point, at least.

Answer (score 0):

Simply navigate to the parent directory of the new repo (i.e. the directory in which you want the clone to reside).