# deploying to AppHarbor using subversion

Tags: asp.net-mvc, git, svn, appharbor

I have an Asp.Net MVC project.

I added "login with Google" button.

It appears this will work only after I publish my site and register it with Google.

Now I need to deploy my site somewhere. I thought to use Appharbor.

However my site's code is in Subversion.

From AppHarbor site:

> You can push .NET code to Appharbor using Git, Mercurial, **Subversion**
>   or Team Foundation Server with the complimentary Git service or
>   through integrations offered in collaboration with Bitbucket, CodePlex
>   and GitHub. AppHarbor has an API so you can build additional
>   integrations yourself.

I saw this one also
[Pushing an existing svn repository to git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8078467/pushing-an-existing-svn-repository-to-git)

Got some questions:

**1.** My site is not meant to be open source.

If I push to free Git - does it has to be open-source?

**2.** In my current situation,

how can I deploy my site on AppHarbor (or like) for free and easliy?

**3.** Is there any integated Appharbor tool to NuGet?

**4.** Is there really no way to deploy from SVN to Appharbor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a private account at one of the mentioned hosters, your only choice is [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org).
Their [free plan](https://bitbucket.org/plans) includes unlimited private Git and Mercurial repositories (the only limitation is that no more than five users, including you) can access the private repositories.

GitHub offers private repositories as well, [but not for free](https://github.com/plans).
CodePlex is completely free, [but allows only open source projects at all](http://codeplex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Project%20hosting%20requirements&referringTitle=CodePlex%20FAQ) (no private projects).

---

**EDIT:**

With "integrated Appharbor tool to NuGet", do you mean AppHarbor pulling NuGet packages, so that you don't have to commit them to your repository?
If yes, check out [Use NuGet Package Restore to avoid pushing packages to AppHarbor](http://blog.appharbor.com/2012/02/06/use-nuget-package-restore-to-avoid-pushing-packages-to-appharbor). Is that what you want?
*Disclaimer: I have absolutely no experience with AppHarbor, so I don't know whether this works. I just found that link by googling!*

---

**EDIT 2:**

As far as I understand, [you can push your code directly to AppHarbor, but only with Git](http://support.appharbor.com/kb/getting-started/deploying-your-first-application-using-git).
Another possible way is to set up Appharbor so that it pulls from a GitHub/Bitbucket/CodePlex repository.
So you'd just have to push to the repository and AppHarbor would get your stuff from there automatically.

But unfortunately that's not possible in your situation, because of your requirements of SVN and closed source. The only hosting site of those three that has SVN support is CodePlex, but on the other hand it's the only site of those three that doesn't allow closed source projects at all.

But there is one workaround that I can think of:
There are tools to [use Git](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-svn.html) [and HG](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/HgSubversion) together with SVN.
I never tried either of these, but I just noticed that git-svn seems to support using Subversion as a client to a Git repository (until now, I always thought that these extensions could only use Git or HG as clients to a SVN repository).
So you could use git-svn to push your changes with Subversion to a Git repository at AppHarbor...

Comment: Is there any integated Appharbor tool to NuGet?

Comment: I meant to deploy the sln from vs2010 directly to Appharbor

Comment: If you want to use SVN, you can use the [CodePlex integration](http://blog.appharbor.com/2011/8/26/announcing-codeplex-integration), although unfortunately, you can't have permanently private repos on CodePlex.

Answer (score 0):

Now appharbor support SVN as well http://blog.appharbor.com/2012/07/26/new-add-on-svnsailor